# remove plural while using stanford pos tagger

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to replace plural to singular (e.g. from girls to girl) using Stanford tagger.

```
private static final String vbnTag = "VBN";
private static final String vbdTag = "VBD";
private static final String jjTag = "JJ";
private static final String edSuff = "ed";
private static final String enSuff = "en";
private static final String oneSt = "1";
private static final String naWord = "NA";

private static final Pattern stopper = Pattern.compile("(?i:and|or|but|,|;|-|--)");
private static final Pattern vbnWord = Pattern.compile("(?i:have|has|having|had|is|am|are|was|were|be|being|been|'ve|'s|s|'d|'re|'m|gotten|got|gets|get|getting)"); // cf. list in EnglishPTBTreebankCorrector
```

Am I doing right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with the help of lemmatization annotation provided in Stanford core NLP.

Comment: Thank you RajuPenumatsa I am going to try it